# Build Failed Reason :app:compileDebugKotlin, can anyone have idea about this gradle build error?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The build is failing with the following error message.

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected 
 void java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle) accessible: module
 java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @76e041cf
```

Comment: Is this error coming on opening Android Studio?

Comment: No, today I updated Android Studio to Bumblebee, when I tried to run the app, this error takes place @SujalKumar

Comment: @ArjunVyas There are a lot of bugs in Bumblebee. maybe we will have to wait for a stable update.